# Wicket AJAX Table row addition not working

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have got some code, written by someone else. The situation is that there is a table on the page, which initially has one row. There is an Add Row button that adds a row to the table. Till now it was repainting the entire page, Now I have been assigned the task to `Ajax-ify` the addition of rows. But when I press the add row button, I get a message like 
 `Ajax POST stopped because of precondition check, url ....`

Here is the code:

The HTML:

```
<div id="tablebg">
                <table class="borderbg"  wicket:id="table"> //this will be the web markup container
                    <tr class="thead">
                        <th class="stylethLeft"></th>
                        <th class="styleth">Foo</th>
                        <th class="styleth">Bar</th>
                        <th class="styleth">Baz</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr wicket:id="gpOffRow">
                        <td class="tdstyle_serial_number" wicket:id="sno">1</td>
                        <td class="td_address" id="alpha"><input type="text"
                            wicket:id="address" class="styledinput" /></td>
                        <td class="td_twochars" id="alpha"><select wicket:id="country"
                            class="styledSelect">
                                <option>NL</option>
                                <option>UK</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td class="td_phone" id="number"><input type="text"
                            wicket:id="telephone" class="styledinput" /></td>

                    </tr>



                </table>
            </div>
```

The Java Code:

```
public class GpOfficePage extends WebPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Form<Void> form;

private GeneralPartner generalPartner;
private List<GpOffice> gpOfficeRows;
private WebMarkupContainer wmc=null;

private String editOrNew;

public GpOfficePage(GeneralPartner gp, String editOrNew) {

    this.generalPartner = gp;
    this.editOrNew = editOrNew;

    add(new TopPanel("topPanel", "General Partner Offices details"));

    add(new FeedbackPanel("gpOffFeedback"));

    form = new Form<Void>("gpOffForm");
    add(form);
    wmc=new WebMarkupContainer("table");
    form.add(Commons.createCancelButton("cancelButton"));
    form.add(createSaveNextButton("saveNextButton"));
    form.add(createAjaxButton("addRowButton",form,wmc));
    form.add(wmc);
```

The list view:

```
ListView<GpOffice> gpo = new ListView<GpOffice>("blah",
            blah) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<GpOffice> item) {

            item.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<blahblah>(item
                    .getModel()));

            item.add(new Label("sno", new Integer(item.getIndex())
                    .toString()));

            TextField<String> addressTf = new TextField<String>("address");
            addressTf.setRequired(true);
            item.add(addressTf);

            DropDownChoice<Country> countryList = new DropDownChoice<Country>(
                    "country",
                    new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Country>>() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        protected List<Country> load() {
                            ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>(); 
                            Country c1 = new Country(); 
                            c1.setName("INR"); 
                            c1.setIsoCode("INR");
                            countries.add(c1); 

                            Country c2 = new Country(); 
                            c2.setName("INR2"); 
                            c2.setIsoCode("INR2");
                            countries.add(c2);
                            return countries;
                        }
                    });
            item.add(countryList);

            TextField<String> telephoneTf = new TextField<String>(
                    "telephone");
            item.add(telephoneTf);
        }
    };
    wmc.add(gpo);//add to the WebMarkupContainer
```

And the `createAjaxButton()` Method

```
private AjaxButton createAjaxButton(final String id, Form<?> form, final WebMarkupContainer wmc){
System.out.println("LOOK HERE"+" "+ wmc.size()+" "+wmc.getMarkupId());
    AjaxButton ajaxButton=new AjaxButton(id){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form){    

            target.add(wmc);


        }
        @Override
        protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form){}

    };

    return ajaxButton;
}
```

What might be wrong here ? thanks

Comment: You might find this Wicket in Action article helpful: [Repainting only newly-created repeater items via ajax](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/)

Comment: Which version of Apache Wicket are you using?

Comment: I got the problem, I created a reduced case and found that I was not re adding the list view, It solved the problem. In the above code there is a problem of scope. Thanks anyway